Is there a survival limit to cultural awareness?
Consider as a culture any understanding of something. Philosophy as a culture of people discussing, and transmitting their discussions. Science as made of people, exchanging knowledge, ideas, hypotheses, observations, interpretations, results. A cultural understanding of anything as made up of people.
Such culture is similar to a complex organism, with people as its cells. The organism depends on the cells to survive, the culture needs its people to be taken in, but more importantly culture and organisms need to survive AS AN ENSEMBLE, which is not necessarily linked to individual people or cells.
Imagine now that the culture allows the people to understand in intricate details that its survival comes sometimes at the expense of at least some of the people. Would such an understanding not be harmful to itself? Within an ecosystem of beliefs, would a culture be less competitive if it allowed its cells/individuals to be aware of the culture that they are part of?
Given this definition:

Cultural awareness is the awareness of individual humans of the larger system as an entity that they take in and transmit. The awareness is that the system could be beneficial or detrimental, in general or specific ways, to some of the individual humans, depending on its own need to survive.

Within this context, could there be a limit, or at the very least an obstacle, to cultural awareness?
Consider it like this problem that got stuck in my head. This problem that I feel I need an answer to. The problem that I feel if I do not solve I am stuck trying to solve, and as my energy is drained into it, and the nature of the problem gets less and less palpable, I find myself paralysed. So I try to understand this paralysis, try to put words on it. But as I express it, I feel I should avoid it, because it feels unanswerable. And I feel other people might need to avoid it, because it is unanswerable, it drains your energy, and paralyses you. This problem has an effect; it paralyses you. Therefore it exists. Yet sharing it might paralyse you. So, it is either shared, and stopped in its tracks because it is unclear, cannot be formulated, drains your energy and paralyses you. Or it is limited to me. This is the pattern I try to understand. Can it be understood, or is there an incentive to avoid it altogether that makes it even more unanswerable, and therefore even more paralysing.

It's rather unclear to me what you mean by "cultural self-awareness". The cells in my body are not aware of me. Is the cultural self-awareness something that is accessible to individual humans? It's also not clear to me what "being competitive" and "surviving" means for a culture. If one is taken up inside another one (like the mitochondria in our cells), would it then have "survived"? What are the borders of a "culture"?

I would define in a first instance cultural self-awareness to be the awareness of individual humans of the larger system as an entity that they take in and transmit. The awareness is that the system could be beneficial or detrimental, in general or specific ways, to some of the individual humans, depending on its own need to survive.

Surviving would be just to exist as a culture. Being taught, being transmitted. Mitochondria would in that sense survive. As for the borders of a culture, I don't know

The terminology is odd. Self-awareness is awareness of self. An individual in a hive mind aware of that hive mind is not aware of self, it is only the hive mind itself that would be self-aware that way. But whether a hive mind needs to put up a veil over individuals constituting it to function properly is an interesting question. We do not know of any genuine hive minds constituted by mind-possessing individuals (culture is a 'mind' only metaphorically), but communal ideology and propaganda might be just the veil needed to maintain community's cohesion.

@Conifold I am thinking of economist Hyman Minsky who argues that each human agent in the population of agents has a model for the political institutions and for the other agents in the population. George Soros embeds something similar into his theory of reflexivity. Self-awareness depends on some cells in the body more than others. Cultural customs, and self-awareness of those customs, depend on a self-aware population of persons who persist the habits and customs of the society.  A self-aware individual can sacrifice many but not all cells. A self-aware culture can sacrifice many persons.

That would be considering human culture (or cultures) as whole(s). But take cultural awareness as the organism we are considering, and the discussion is different. I guess the problem of taking a living organism as an example is that it is relatively easy to define the boundaries of an organism, but less so for a culture. I guess I imagine a more limited set of beliefs, which are minimally required to make up cultural awareness.

I'm sorry Sébastien, I don't understand the question.

I also would like to understand the question, but still don't really understand it. What motivates your idea that there might be a limit or obstacle to the self-awareness? And limit presumably means that the awareness would not be realistic somehow or only up to some degree?

Should be obvious. Gurdjieff: If humans understood why they are planted on that remote planet, they would, on principle, kill themselves. The more prosaic understanding of that which is generally accepted: Birthrate and education are in inverse relation. More topical

I am not sure any of the 3 to 4 opinions you presented @Rushi are a definitive proof of anything. Although I indeed wonder whether there is a mechanism that precludes the understanding of certain structures of our societies that might be representative of our reality, helpful to understand, because they paralyse (via pessimism or other) the ability to adapt or just survive.

Although I indeed wonder whether there is a mechanism that precludes the understanding... — SPOT ON! Gurdjieff called it the 'kundabuffer". Nowadays we can say "The Matrix"

Note: You don't really need to go new age; traditional systems have it also. The dukha-tanha knot of Buddhism, the ahankar-maya knot of Hinduism. Even in Christianity which has a low stock nowadays ☺️, sin in the Greek origina meant Archer missing the mark and didn't have the sermonizing/moralizing of latter day Christianity

I don't think this can be a good translation into English from any language. Can you say in what language the Question arose?

I am French speaking if you need to know, but even in French I would find it difficult to formulate the question. You could formulate it as "Is there a hindrance to the survival of an understanding (as an element of culture made of people) due to the awareness of the adverse effects of the understanding on the people having that understanding, if you consider that the understanding includes the awareness of these adverse effects?". but is is quite a mouthful.

Or what about this one: "Do certain social awarenesses have systematic incentives against them, or are the incentives always contextual?" @Robbie Goodwin
